# How can I make a virtual pc of a certain one?

Tags: laptop, microsoft-virtual-pc

I would like to make a virtual pc of one I use at the university in order to run it in my laptop. I want to do it because I have some programs in the one I use at the university and I still haven´t found a way to install them in my laptop.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sysinternals has [disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415)
which should get you started